# Frequency of relatively prime pairs in all pairs

Tags: probability, number-theory

What would be the probability of getting a relatively prime pair if we pick two random numbers in natural number set? What if we pick more than two number?

Comment: for two it is $6/\pi^2$

Comment: If you're picking three numbers do you still want to know the probability of getting (at least) one relatively prime pair?  Or is it a relatively prime triplet?  Or is it a triplet of pairwise relatively prime numbers?

Comment: There is no such thing as "picking two random numbers in natural number set". What do you actually mean?

Comment: You understand what i mean. Say for example what is the probability if I set a bound let's say numbers up to 100. Then finding a relationship between the result and 100, then taking limit to infinity should make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Of all natural numbers, $1/p$ of them are divisible by $p$.  For two randomly chosen natural numbers, the probability they are both divisible by $p$ is then $1/p^2$.  Thus, the probability at least one of them is $\textbf{not}$ divisible by $p$ is $1-1/p^2$.

Therefore, the probability that at least one is not divisible by $2$, $\textbf{and}$ at least one is not divisible by $3$, $\textbf{and}$ at least one of them is not divisible by $5$, $\textbf{and}$ at least one is not divisible by $7$, $\textbf{and}$ at least one is not divisible by $11$, ... etc (or in other words, the two numbers are coprime) is given by the product

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5^2} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{7^2} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{11^2} \right) \cdots$$

If we look at the reciprocal of this product, it is simply

$$\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^2}} \right)\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3^2}} \right)\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{5^2}} \right)\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{7^2}} \right)\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{11^2}} \right)\cdots$$

each factor of which is a geometric series

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\ldots \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{3^6}+\ldots \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{5^4}+\frac{1}{5^6}+\ldots \right)\cdots$$

which multiplies out to give the sum

$$1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\ldots$$

which converges to exactly $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (see the Basel problem).

Therefore, the probability that two randomly chosen natural numbers are coprime is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Ok then. The definite answer comes from limiting sum of phi function to infinity and looking for asymptotic behaviour. How about direct computation with using divisibilities? I mean we can create a series to solve this problem. Let's only calculate the case where our numbers in the pair cannot be both divided by 2 or 3 or 5. That is to say,

(1/4 + 1/9 + 1/25) - (1/4.9 + 1/4.25 + 1/9.25 ) + 1/4.9.25 = 0.36

1 - 0.36 = 0.64 which is a good approximation for actual result that is about 0.601..

Similarly we can do an analog for more than two number case.
Let's write an analog of above expression for 3 number case.

(1/8 + 1/27 + 1/ 125) - (1/8.27 + 1/8.125 + 1/27.125) + 1/8.27.125 = 0.164..

1-0.164 = 0.836..

I think this method is reliable, but i need verification.

Comment: This solution suggests you are looking for relatively prime $k$-tuples.  In this case the (limiting) probability for any $k\ge 2$ is just $1/\zeta(k)$, so for $k=3$ that's $\approx 0.8319$.